# Python: negative numbers, when multiplying a matrix by a vector with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
A = numpy.matrix([[36, 34, 26],
        [18, 44,  1],
        [11, 31, 41]])

X1 = numpy.matrix([[46231154], [26619349], [37498603]])
```

Need multiplying a matrix by a vector. I tried:

```
>>>A*X1
   matrix([[ -750624208],
        [ 2040910731],
        [-1423782060]])
>>> numpy.dot(A,X1)
   matrix([[ -750624208],
        [ 2040910731],
        [-1423782060]])
```

Why negative numbers? It's ok with lower numbers, for example:

```
A = numpy.matrix([[36, 34, 26],
        [18, 44,  1],
        [11, 31, 41]])
X1 = numpy.matrix([[8], [6], [6]])

>>>A*X1
matrix([[58],
        [38],
        [40]])
```

Comment: I agree with Robert. Here is the result from the 64-bit python on my machine: >>> A = numpy.matrix([[36, 34, 26], [18, 44, 1], [11, 31, 41]]) >>> >>> X1 = numpy.matrix([[46231154], [26619349], [37498603]]) >>> A*X1 matrix([[3544343088], [2040910731], [2871185236]]) >>> numpy.dot(A,X1) matrix([[3544343088], [2040910731], [2871185236]]) >>> and here is the result from 32-bit Python2.7-32: >>> A = numpy.matrix([[36, 34, 26], ... [18, 44, 1], ... [11, 31, 41]]) >>> >>> X1 = numpy.matrix([[46231154], [26619349], [37498603]]) >>> A*X1 matrix([[ -750624208], [ 2040910731], [-1423782060]]) >>> numpy.d

Comment: Thank you, Robert, it's ok now with dtype=np.int64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're on a 32-bit system, and you're seeing an integer overflow. Try defining the matrix and vector with the keyword argument `dtype=np.int64`, and see if you get a more meaningful answer.

On my 64 bit machine, I have the following output

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: A = numpy.matrix([[36, 34, 26],
   ...:         [18, 44,  1],
   ...:         [11, 31, 41]])

In [3]:

In [3]: X1 = numpy.matrix([[46231154], [26619349], [37498603]])

In [4]: A*X1
Out[4]:
matrix([[3544343088],
        [2040910731],
        [2871185236]])
```